# What is the name of Opus No. 8 by Nikolay Ladukhin?

Tags: classical-music, piano

This is a question regarding an historical Russian composer.

I have done much research regarding the works of Nikolay Ladukhin (Russian: Николай Михайлович Ладухин). However, piecing together a more complete list of his works has been a challenge.

In particular, I'd like to know the title of his Op. 8. I know that Op. 8, **No. 3** is entitled "The Lake" but I cannot find the name of the complete opus.

Or else, pointing me to a source that has a more exhaustive list of Russian compositions might be helpful.